# Meaning of "crowded out"

Tags: meaning, verbs

What does *crowded out* mean in the following sentence?

> Adultery and theft of food or animals were **crowded out** by highway
>   robbery, pickpocketing and other crimes common to an increasingly
>   industrial and urbanized center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When X *crowds out* Y, X is replacing Y by pushing Y out.  In this case, pickpocketing (etc.) replaced theft of animals (etc.) since it became more popular and hence more common.